# Libsoup error encountered when updating openSUSE using zypper

Tags: opensuse, zypper

I'm using openSUSE Leap 15.5 and zypper version 1.14.68

Upon startup, the system will attempt to run the updater, which fails. In order to get a more detailed error, I updated manually using:

```
sudo zypper update
```

I receive the following error:

> File './x86_64/libsoup-3_0-0-3.0.4-150400.1.6.x86_64.rpm' not found on medium 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/Leap:/15.5/standard/'

This error then prevents zypper from updating other packages as well (if I proceed with using the 'ignore' command). I'm trying to make sense of this error, but not quite sure where to start.

It appears that it has the incorrect repository listed for an important dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you have an incorrect repo.

It should be `https://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.5/repo/oss/`

Comment: Right...not sure how this happened - how do I correct it?

Comment: using 'zypper lr -u' I can see that 'openSUSE:Leap:15.5' is set to "https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/Leap:/15.5/standard/"

Comment: Either edit the files directly in `/etc/zypper/repos.d`, or run `yast2 repositories`.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I ended up editing the repo in vim...but now I've found the yast ui (which is much nicer than the yast terminal ui). I feel like openSUSE have made some of this overly complex...but that's a different discussion.